# Align Vertically my div

Tags: css

Why my div `<div class="two">` didint align verticaly at the middle event after i put `vertical-align: middle;`

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Hz4zz/)

HTML :

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.main {
    border: 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;  
}

.one {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    display: inline-block;
}

.two {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    vertical-align: middle;    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `vertical-align:middle` on `one`, and `two`. That way the vertical middle of `one` is aligned with the vertical middle of `two`. You could also just put `vertical-align:middle` on `one` which will align its vertical middle position to the baseline vertical position of `two`.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Hz4zz/3/)**

Comment: so i have to align always the first one ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Add `vertical-align:middle` rule to `.one` class

```
.one {
   width: 70px;
   height: 70px;
   background-color: antiquewhite;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle; /* Adde Rule */
}
```

### [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hz4zz/2/)